# PHP How can I get the file's name when it is too large?

Tags: javascript, php, upload

How can I get the file's name when it is too large?

I can get its length using `$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']` but what about its name?

```
// check that post_max_size has not been reached
// convert_to_bytes is the function turn `5M` to bytes because $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] is in bytes.
if (isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']) 
    && (int) $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] > convert_to_bytes(ini_get('post_max_size'))) 
{
  // ... with your logic
  throw new Exception('File too large!');
}
```

for instance, if I upload an mp3,

```
very-large.mp3 (size 11MB)
```

I would like to get its name which is `very-large.mp3` is it possible? Or do I have to use javascript?

**NOTE:**

You will get

`Array()`

with `$_FILES` when the file is too large.

So then you can't get `$_FILES[file]["name"]`

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for, but are you talking about [`$_FILES[file]["name"]` and `$_FILES[file]["size"]`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)?

Comment: you'll get `Array
(
)` with `$_FILES` when the file is too large. How can you then get `$_FILES[file]["name"]`???

Comment: Please don't tag questions with "php-5.5" unless they are about features specific in PHP 5.5. Don't use the tag to tell us which version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

So if you have `<input type="file" name="userFile"/>` than you use it's name to get name from `$_FILES` global variable: `echo "File {$_FILES['userFile']['name']} is too big.";`

Comment: no , you will get `Array ( )` with `$_FILES` How can you then get `$_FILES['userFile']["name"]`???

Comment: AFAICS OP wants to get the name of the file which has **not** been uploaded due to size limitation. In his case, `$_FILES` Array is empty, and that's what he's trying to say.